# Unexplained exception thrown by calling deallocate from a custom allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management

Visual Studio doesn't explain anything to me, it just breaks and sends me conveniently to the `operator delete` implementation....

Why is it unable to deallocate?

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Allocator
{
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using pointer = T*;

    pointer allocate(size_type n)
    {
        return static_cast<pointer>(::operator new(n * sizeof(T)));
    }

    void deallocate(pointer p)
    {
        ::operator delete((void*)p);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Allocator<int> al;

    int a = 5;
    int* p = al.allocate(1);
    p = &a;
    al.deallocate(p);
}
```

Comment: That simple program you show *should* work just fine. Are you doing something you don't show us? If you enable more warnings do you get any?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Apologies. Missed a few details. Edited.

Comment: So you deallocate a variable with automatic storage and wonder why it breaks?

Comment: When you do `p = &a`, it's the same as doing `int i = 5; i = 34;`  and then wonder why `i` no longer is `5`. You first make `p` point to some memory (that you allocate dynamically), then you make `p` point to some *other* memory, loosing the original pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deallocating something else other than what you allocated.

You are allocating, assigning the result to `p`, then immediately overwrite the result with some other, random pointer, which you attempt to deallocate.

The reason for your crash should be obvious.

P.S. As far as Visual Studio goes, it correctly brings you to the line where the illegal memory access occured. Sadly, the state of modern technology is not yet to the point where you also get a detailed explanation of what exactly went wrong, at that point.

Comment: I am not sure it is a sad thing. The moment it happens, we all would be flipping burgers.